# Types of research papers

Tags: publications, research-topic

There are research papers that focus on the presentation and analysis of application of a specific idea on a specific subject; e.g. how a closed-loop (in contradiction to an open-loop) can help patients with early symptoms of Parkinson's disease, experiencing low-amplitude tremor. It includes the application of a specific method (closed-loop) to a specific case of study (Parkinson's disease, early symptoms) using measurements and experimental data that are relevant to this study only and could probably not be useful under a different set of assumptions.

There are also other types of papers where the authors only need to give a general scope a method or set of methods, without considering the uniqueness of any specific case, and by using simpler models and more general assumptions; e.g. how to use closed-loop interventions, to shift brain activity from an initial arbitrary pattern to another.

Are there names for these two types of research papers, based on the above distinction?